# Excel "method displayalerts of object Application failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I've problem with Excel file set as variant in SAP report. When I open it directly in SAP macro:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Headers").Delete
Worksheets("RawData").Delete
Worksheets("Header").Delete
Worksheets("XXXXXXXXXX").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

is getting error:

> method displayalerts of object Application failed

When I open the same file, but from my hard drive, everything works well, any ideas?

Comment: What is "SAP macro"? How do you "open it directly in SAP macro"? How do you "set as variant in SAP report" the Excel file?

Comment: It's possible `Application` is not referring to Excel (or at least, not the right instance).  Try adding `debug.print application.name` immediately before this code and see what it outputs.  Difficult to make suggestions without knowing exactly how the macros are run.